# Why does this Stack Overflow API query return binary data?

Tags: support, status-completed, api

The Stack Overflow API query

> http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/search?tagged=javascript&intitle=%3Cdiv%3E

returns what appears to be binary data:

> ���`I�%&/m�{J�J��t��`$ؐ@�������iG#)�*��eVe]f@�흼��{����{����;�N'���?\fdl��J�ɞ!���?~|?"��Ey�')=��y6�����h����z��<=���~|W>�Z5�u�A:�f��/>����y�(��G�d^ϲe��!z���Ѳ�Y)5��G��A�8�VeU?������/I=����Yd�E��n�գt����/�q�
>   �IU�n �ۻ�/No�������N�|�
>   ��&�}�0��euU���?_O�Y��T˦*s�3�0_�/�    �ۼV�@ʄJ��TH�����Y>���-���tY-���e^7�U���ŋ:�[�`��+�'U�V�G����]�ݻU��e��F�v{^/gy]�{�#����.���u��su�S��]���Uq�?��'賏��E�d��
>   B����w�^�5�[�*-���w?N�W���2����:�*f���ݝ��=�,|�+h~�%�{��.���0�;J]�-�������E��l���q]d�(�vN����(�<_�����z�:[6ۯ��u�գ��_M^�id����i�L�b%3�����x�fn��Ll5%�����v��
>   �f������m�nh���&o�by��D��F�@��/�
>   @��6+�&����~��5A��-�,�+B��U�����9wE�5}�5$w��aS���(�WW�b���'�uuECh�z�\����Y��K�tN�8�Ҍ�����S�#P1}S�����7H"F�ʧ�y1�!.���.�ie��7
>   +������FID����Y�KR Ly���^��i�]kROK��E��=��'�i�7��dMA��:Ĺº���:|cy|���%���n�
>   �i�|��!"Q�yA�m���,����Z�Y
>   n`��fKH���r�(g�����c�Oq~�w��B�Y~����U.<�c����?~���S��'v]UŒ�6��W��������Uܗ��Zg�3O�lq-@�1���_�ybq�=�O�����?���8<��

Why?

Comment: I think it is a gzipped api response

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASP.NET was freaking out about the `<` in your search term.

Fixed it*.

More generally, the API always returns compressed content; so everything is "binary," this case just showed it more obviously due to the unusual error.

<sub>*It's worth noting that the actual `<` and `>` are not indexed by our Lucene search provider, so you can't actually search for `<div>`: you'll be searching for `div` instead.  It doesn't explode anymore if you try though.</sub>

Comment: But I guess it's hard to make error pages return the correct encoding headers too? (Just like the 200 OK response does.)

Comment: @Arjan - *most* error pages do, this particular one was well ahead of our code in the pipeline though.

Comment: No worries, if a 500 error ever shows again, the search for the binary data will point folks to this very question! ;-) (Well, at least the Google search does!)

Answer (score 2):

I guess there are two problems:

1. Leaving out the opening `%3C` does show (different?) results, so why does that opening bracket have this effect?
2. With the opening angle bracket, this yields an ASP error page, but gzipped. However, the response headers don't say it's compressed, leaving the browser (or whatever application is handling this) oblivious about it:

   ```
   curl -o output.txt -v --compressed \
   http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/search?tagged=javascript\&intitle=%3Cdiv%3E

   > GET /1.1/search?tagged=javascript&intitle=%3Cdiv%3E HTTP/1.1
   > User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (universal-apple-darwin10.0) libcurl/7.19.7 [...]
   > Host: api.stackoverflow.com
   > Accept: */*
   > Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip

   < HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
   < Cache-Control: private
   < Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
   < X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
   < Date: Fri, 01 Apr 2011 09:22:43 GMT
   < Content-Length: 1194
   ```

   However, manually uncompressing does result in an *"Server Error in '/' Application"* [error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G80n7.png). Also, a normal response *does* include the proper header:

   ```
   < HTTP/1.1 200 OK
   < Cache-Control: private
   < Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
   < Content-Encoding: gzip
   < [...]
   ```